# JavaScript support via SocketMobile SDK

Tags: barcode-scanner, socketscan

I developed an MVC 4.0/C# in house application with extensive use of JavaScript.  I Purchased the SocketScan 10 SKD/API's from the Socket Mobile store for my CHS 7Pi scanner and would like to know if it supports the use of JavaScript functions to manipulate scanner functionality?

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Use HID mode

In HID mode, the scanner behaves like a keyboard and "types" the barcode wherever the cursor is located.

#### Option 2: Custom Webview

If you are deploying your web app on mobile devices, you may be able to write a javascript interface which exposes the ScanAPI sdk for your platform to the webview where your web app is hosted.

**disclaimer**: I am a consultant to Socket Mobile